# SQL Azure Billing - Transition multiple DB on a single server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, billing

I'm trying to get some clarification on the billing terminology for SQL Azure... We currently have an in-house SQL Server (2008) from which we run multiple databases. The SQL Azure billing documentation lists prices based on DB size - for instance, a flat $9.99 for 100MB-1GB.

So, if I were to move my entire SQL backend to Azure would I be charged for each individual DB, or would the size (and thus price) be calculated as a sum of all the individual databases?

Thanks in advance,
James

Answer (score 6):

Price is size per database. So if you have the following databases..

Database A - 900mb
Database b - 1.5 GB
Database c - 5mb

You'd be charged $4.995 + $9.99 + ($9.99 + $3.996) = $28.971 per month.

At least to keep things simple. :) If you start getting into daily averages, that number could change.